# Getting positional audio in cocos2d v3

Tags: audio, cocos2d-iphone, openal, objectal

I'm having some trouble using OpenAL in cocos2d v3. Here's some context:

What I'm using: Xcode 5 + cocos2d v3 + iPhone 5 (iOS 7).

What I want to do: Create a multi-audio-source scene with positional audio (just pan + volume for now).

Why didn't I use OALSimpleAudio? Couldn't get the various sources to change pan and volumes as the listener moves.

What have I done so far? I have loaded an ALBuffer with an audio file and queued that buffer in a ALSource. When I run the code, nothing ever plays. Right after the `[soundSource play:soundBuffer ...]` line, I have checked if the sound was playing with `[soundSource playing]` and got a negative response. Also tried to instantiate an ALListener, with the same position as the source, but nothing changed.

Any help regarding this problem would be appreciated. Any suggestions about what different approaches I should be looking forward to are welcome as well.

Thank You!